# creating power group

Tags: 12.04, sudo, workgroup

I want to create a group that can run some privileged commands but not all. For example, a power user can access the home files (from one user to another), but it shouldn't be allowed to run apt-get command.

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `sudoers` mechanism you can give specific privilege to a specific user or group.
To edit the `/etc/sudoers` file you need to use `visudo`.

e.g. to give or negate only some specific commands to the user *igor* you can add the line

```
 igor    ALL=(ALL) /bin/kill, /usr/bin/, !/usr/bin/apt-get
```

in this example the user *igor* can execute with sudo all the command in `/usr/bin` the command `/bin/kill` but not `/usr/bin/apt-get`.
The command’s paths are separated one from another by comma `,` and negated by `!`

To give or negate the **root access to a group**, for a set of commands you can add the line

```
 %geeks ALL = (root) /usr/bin/,!/usr/bin/apt-get,!/usr/bin/aptitude,!/usr/bin/dpkg
```

in this case you will give to the *geeks* group the root access to all the commands in /usr/bin with the exceptions of `apt-get` `aptitude` and `dpkg`.

To add to the group *geeks* the user *igor*  e.g. you can write

```
# sudo usermod -a -G geeks igor
```

Linux has inherited from UNIX the concept of ownerships and permissions for files. 
This means that even without root access users belonging to the same group can share files among them and not with the rest of the world. With `ls -l` you will notice in the left part a string like this

```
-rw-r--r--   1  igor  geeks  1892  Jul 10  18:30 The_not_so_short.pdf
```

From left to right this string means `-rwxrw-r--` that: (first position) is not a special file or directory (there is a dash `-` that means this attribute is off),`rwx` Read Write eXecute allowed to user himself (first block of 3), `rw-` Read Write No eXecute for the users of his group (second block of 3), `r--` Read, No Write, No eXecute for the other users (third block of 3). It's possible to toggle each single attributes for each single file or directory.

To give instead to this group the possibility *only to change directory* regardless of the permission it's hard. It doesn't exists an executable command `cd` because each command is executed in a child process and can affect only its current working directory and not the parent's one. [It's better explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3741190/3569208). So to change directory you need to give the possibility to execute a `shell` as root, and it means you are practically giving full privileges...

References and further readings:

- `man sudoers`, `man visudo` and of course `man sudo`
- [How to give root access to a group for a few commands only](http://linuxg.net/how-to-give-root-access-to-a-group-for-a-few-commands-only/)
- [Linux / Unix Command: sudoers](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl5_sudoers.htm)